# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "weitergehen" und "weitermachen"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

Ist *weitermachen* ein Wort, das nur für Menschen benutzt wird? Wird *weitergehen* auf die gleiche Weise für z. B. eine Ausstellung benutzt?

Answer (score 4):

The part "*weiter-*" means: "To continue to do something".

Example: "*weiterschlafen*" means: "To continue to sleep".

This can be done with most verbs.

The verb "*machen*" (in this context) means: "To do something".

So the verb "*weitermachen*" means: "To continue to do something".

The verb "*gehen*" has a lot of meanings. In the context of an event it often means: "To take place".

So "*weitergehen*" (in this context) means: "To continue to take place".

Comment: "Weitergehen" also means, quite literally, "continue walking", perhaps in the sense of "don't stop"-

Answer (score 2):

This is about the different translations of the English verb **to continue**, I guess.

> Das Konzert geht weiter.

*The concert continues.*

> Wir machen mit dem Konzert weiter.

*We continue with the concert.*

There's a change of the subject. In the first sentence, it's *the concert* which does something. In the second, it's *we*.

As you found out already, **weitergehen** in the meaning *to continue* can only be applied to things. When applied to persons, it means **to continue walking** specifically, which is not what you meant.

> Es geht weiter.

*It continues.* ("Es" is an event or similar thing.)

*"It" **continues walking**.* ("Es" is a person or anything with legs to walk, but the noun used is of the neuter class, e.g. *das Mädchen*.)

> Sie geht weiter.

*"She" continues.* ("Sie" is an event or similar thing, but the noun is of the female class, e.g. *die Tagung*.)

*She **continues walking**.* ("Sie" is a person or anything with legs to walk.)

(If you wonder how comes "Sie" can be a thing, remember German "genders" are only noun classes and have no meaning on top of this.)